# How to fade in and out with Vue

Tags: jquery, vue.js, vuejs2, css-animations, vue-component

I need help with Animations with Vue I have a notification I'm only displaying when there is a message in state(`this.$store.state.message`), so I have my notification element like this

```
<!-- This is the notification -->
    <template v-if="this.$store.state.status">
        <div
          class="login-toastr login-success show-login-toastr"
          v-if="this.$store.state.status == 'success'"
        >
          <p>{{ this.$store.state.message }}</p>
        </div>

        <div class="login-toastr login-failed" v-else-if="this.$store.state.status !== 'success'">
          <p>{{ this.$store.state.message }}</p>
        </div>
    </template>
```

The thing is, I want the notification to fade in and out and when it fades out, let the message and status become empty. Please how do I go about this?

I already tried something but it isn't working

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <!-- This is the notification -->
    <template v-if="this.$store.state.status">
      <transition name="fade">
        <div
          class="login-toastr login-success show-login-toastr"
          v-if="this.$store.state.status == 'success'"
        >
          <p>{{ this.$store.state.message }}</p>
        </div>

        <div class="login-toastr login-failed" v-else>
          <!-- <div class="login-toastr login-failed" v-else-if="this.$store.state.status !== 'success'"> -->
          <p>{{ this.$store.state.message }}</p>
        </div>
      </transition>
    </template>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {};
</script>

<style>
.fade-enter {
  opacity: 0;
}

.fade-enter-active {
  transition: opacity 1s;
}

.fade-leave {
  /* opacity: 0; */
}

.fade-leave-active {
  transition: opacity 1s;
  opacity: 0;
}
</style>
```

Also, I'm using jQuery, so if have a suggestion regarding that too.

Comment: Just to be clear, your animations are working just fine - you only want to clear the `this.$store.state.message` after displaying success or failure?

Comment: Yes, that! Although I just observed that the class isn't showing when it gets loaded onto the page until I click the 'x' button to remove it, that's the animation I did starts working, I have no idea why it behaves this way.

My main goal is to remove the 'x' button and have the notification come and go by itself and clears the state when it goes off

Comment: The interpolation using 'this' keyword is wrong. You are usign vuex? If it so, you must use a getter inside a computed property and then access it on your template. Using this inside the template probably is causing your issue.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't quite understand what you mean. I'm still new to Vue

Comment: I think adding mode="in-out" to the transition tag might do it.

Comment: It didn't, still having the same effect :(